# Remove 5 first elements of QMap

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qmap

How can I  remove 5 first elements of a `QMap`?

Comment: Maps don't have an inherent order. What do you mean by the 'first five' elements? Do you mean the first five elements that were added or do your elements in the map have an order they can be sorted by?

Comment: @Nathanael: they have an order, they are ordered by key.

Comment: @Evan Granted that's true. My question is is this the order that the OP wants to use to remove elements? If I have map where the key is a pointer it's true that those elements may be sorted by the value of the pointer. That ordering may not have any meaning however.

Comment: @Nathanael: Well the meaning of the order is up to woody to decide, but `QMap`'s most certainly have a well defined order. And you can in fact remove the first `N` items of a map in terms of that order.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would probably work:

```
const size_t count = std::min<size_t>(5, m.size());
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    m.erase(m.begin());
}
```

---

**DEMO**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    std::map<int,int> m;
    m.insert(std::make_pair(0,0));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(1,1));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(2,2));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(3,3));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(4,4));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(5,5));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(6,6));

    const size_t count = std::min<size_t>(5, m.size());
    for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        m.erase(m.begin());
    }

    for(std::map<int,int>::const_iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << it->second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

---

**DEMO using `QMap`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QMap>

int main() {

    QMap<int,int> m;
    m[0] = 0;
    m[1] = 1;
    m[2] = 2;
    m[3] = 3;
    m[4] = 4;
    m[5] = 5;
    m[6] = 6;

    const size_t count = qMin<size_t>(5, m.size());
    for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        m.erase(m.begin());
    }

    for(QMap<int,int>::const_iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << it.value() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as 'First' and 'Last' in Maps.
its `QMap<Key, T>` while elements are accessed by the Key part, which is usually non-numeric.

Comment: bologna, http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qmap.html specifically says `"When iterating over a QHash, the items are arbitrarily ordered. With QMap, the items are always sorted by key."`